# Downloading facebook comments from personal website

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have a personal website in which I included a facebook comment section. The website has multiple pages and each page has different comments asociated with that page. My question is, is there a way to export these comments in a CSV/Excel file? I know I can manage my comments in the facebookfordevelopers section but I want to download them for further use. I can't seem to find a way of doing this. I was thinking maybe a python script that will iterate through all of the pages will help but with no idea on where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more information what you tried already, and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I have multiple links and I want to extract the comments posted in them using facebook comment section